# check if a uiView has handled touch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, touch

What I want to do is put a `UIView` on top of another `UIView`, and both of them are screen size. The top `UIView` includes lots cocos nodes and will respond when I touch them. But when I touch a place that has no cocos node, the bottom `UIView` should respond. 
I don't know how to do this. My imagine is check if top uiView is handled touch, do nothing. other wise let the bottom `UIView` start respond. But I don't know how to check that. I only know how to check touch but it seems the `UIView` will also be touched when I touch some place it can't handle.

Comment: You can achieve that with one UIView that has other UIViews on it. No need for 2 UIViews as core to begin with.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add top view as the bottom view's `subView`, but I still can't touch the bottom view. might that because there are some invisible layers in top view to handled the touch and block it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you not requires 2 views.

Just take one view only and add all your node to that view.

in .h

```
IBOutlet UIView *bgView;//your view

UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTapRecognizer;// view tap recognizer
```

in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    viewTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handelGesture:)];
    [bgView addGestureRecognizer:viewTapRecognizer];

    for (UIView *subView in [bgView subviews]) {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *nodeTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handelGesture:)];

        [subView addGestureRecognizer:nodeTapRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)handelGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    if (sender == viewTapRecognizer) {
        // your view is tapped
        NSLog(@"........Tapped view..........");
    }
    else {
        // your node is tapped
        NSLog(@"........Tapped node..........");
    }
}
```

Try this. it might work for you.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov please check code first i add UITapGestureRecognizer for each node. so please check it before down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by 2 ways: using *[pointInside...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:)* method or *[hitTest...](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:)* method.
If you will use *pointInside...* you can use only your views (the top view and the bottom view). You will subclass UIView with the top view and override *pointInside...* method. You will return *YES* if user's tapped a cocoa node else returns *NO*.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL inside = [self didUserTapCocoaNode:point];
    return inside;
}
```

If you want more complex logic, you should use third view, subclass of UIView (the container view), that will be contain the top view and the bottom view. Override method *hitTest...*, and return the bottom or the top view.

```
 - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
 {
    UIView* result = nil;
    if ([self touchedCocoaNode:point])
    {
      result = self.topView;
    }
    else
    {
      result = self.bottomView;
    } 

    return result;
 }
```

**UPD** 
Example implementation of *didUserTapCocoaNode* with pseudo code:

```
 - (BOOL)didUserTapCocoaNode:(CGPoint)pointInSelf
{
  __block BOOL tappedSomeNode = NO;
  [self.nodes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NodeType* obj, NSInteger idx, BOOL* stop){
     CGPoint pointInNode = [obj convertPoint:pointInSelf fromView:self];
     tappedSomeNode = [obj pointInside:pointInNode withEvent:nil];
     *stop = tappedSomeNode;
   }]
  return tappedSomeNode;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code. but how to check `didUserTapCocoaNode`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with pseudo code example. Main idea is enumerate all nodes while you does not find touched node. p.s. What is a cocoa node, is it subclass of UIView or some abstract object?